# Download images from String URL Array and save to File?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire

I have an array of urls in string version (I'm using string as they are needed in other parts of my app in string version).

I have converted the strings to urls, and then attempted to use AlamoFire to download the images and then save them with FileManager.

Upon trying this I got nowhere and have looked all over stackoverflow and just confused myself more..

Assuming i have an array of string urls such as

```
["www.url1.com/image1.png","www.url2.com/image2.png"]
```

and the array is anywhere between 5-1000 urls long (depending on the quantity the user selects to be displayed)

How would i go about saving these images to the filemanager or cache so the images aren't re-downloaded each time the view is displayed?. 
Also the images would be named '0.png', '1.png' etc so the name reflects the index they are in the array.

Comment: A better option would be to use https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage or https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage, because those libraries handle all caching operations on images (they download image, save it and load it from file system when you again reference their url), so you don't need to download images, save them, think about naming, caching,....

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, used SDWebImage and its solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Not gonna write the code for you, but here's the general approach I'd take:

1. Use `FileManager` to get the URL for `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory`.

(Swift 4; name may be slightly different in Swift 3, don't remember off the top of my head)

2. Use `.appendingPathComponent` to make a subdirectory named after your app's bundle identifier.
3. Create the subdirectory if it doesn't exist already.
4. Using whatever organizational scheme you like, construct a URL for a file within the subdirectory representing your network URL.
5. Check the URL you just created, to see if the file exists. If it does, read it.
6. If the file in step 5 didn't exist, create the file, download the data from the network, and store it in the file.

Note that this all assumes you've only got one thread reading or writing the cache at a time. If your app is multi-threaded, you'll need to set up appropriate safeguards to prevent race conditions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :) . Vladimir's solution to use SDWebImage has solved the problems I was having.